# No Debug Info in WiX Managed Custom Action using Visual Studio integration

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2008, installation, wix, custom-action

I have managed to create a custom action in C# using `MakeSfxCA` which is mostly working.

However, there is some kinks which needs debugging to sort out. (The "printf-debugging" just is not enough.)

However all debug info is lost.
When MakeSfxCA is called from the Visual Studio project the .pdb-file is not passed as an argument, so no debug-info is included in the created CA-dll.

If I manually run `MakeSfxCA`

```
MakeSfxCA MyDLL.CA.dll SfxCa.dll MyDLL.dll MyDLL.pdb CustomAction.config
```

then the debug-info is included in the created custom-action-dll.

How do I get the WiX-CA-project to add the pdb-info automatically?

/Leif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if I created a project of the type *C# Custom Action Project* then it magically works.

Also I could probably have tried to add a *Post-build event* to my project. Something along the lines of:

```
"C:\Program Files\Windows Installer XML v3\SDK\MakeSfxCA.exe"
      $(TargetDir)$(TargetName).CA.dll 
      "C:\Program Files\Windows Installer XML v3\SDK\x86\SfxCA.dll" 
      $(TargetDir)$(TargetName).dll 
      $(TargetDir)$(TargetName).pdb 
      $(TargetDir)Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll
```

(Haven't tried this though, since I got it working as above.)

/L